# How do I express an empty URL in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3, nsurl

I have an `iOS` project. I'm working on using `Xcode 8` and now `Swift 3`.  Before I started converting my project from `Swift 2` to the latest, I had the following in my `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    // Transfer incoming file to global variable to be read
    if url != "" {

        // Load from Mail App

        incomingFileTransfer = url

        incomingStatus = "Incoming"

    } else {

        // Regular Load

        print("App Delegate: No incoming file")

        incomingFileTransfer = nil

    }

    return true
}
```

Worked great and it would see if there was an incoming PDF type file being opened by the app.  I have PDF files associated with my app and being to open them within my app.

I used the migration tool to help convert my code to the new `Swift 3` code.

It converted my code in the `AppDelegate` and changed it to:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

    // Transfer incoming file to global variable to be read
    if url != "" {

        // Load from Mail App

        incomingFileTransfer = url

        incomingStatus = "Incoming"

    } else {

        // Regular Load

        print("App Delegate: No incoming file")

        incomingFileTransfer = nil

    }

    return true
}
```

However it gives the error:

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'URL' and
>    'String'

I understand the 'open url' that was an `NSURL` is now a type `URL` instead. How do I express an empty URL in Xcode 8 and Swift 3 now?  I looked online and cannot find anything about this?

Thank you for the help and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `absoluteString` property of `URL` to compare is it empty.

```
if url.absoluteString != "" {

}
else {

}
```

**Note:** If you just want to check for empty, then batter to use `isEmpty` property of `String` in your case it is look like `if !url.absoluteString.isEmpty {`